# Do I have to register and make a payment to Apple Developer to create an application for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, mobile, build

Do I have to register and make a payment to Apple Developer to create an application for iOS

Previously I made an application on Flutter then I built the project on iOS, then when I want to configure xcode I have to register for a membership at Apple Developer? Do I have to do this to create an iOS application in a developer environment or upload it to the appstore

Answer (score 1):

You can make them for free locally, you only need to pay for a developer account if you are adding it to the app store.

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: before I was in Android Studio, the project I created was then I built the apk and the results (app_debuk.apk) can be shared with other colleagues. mean for IOS can not be done like that?(free no need to pay)

Comment: Nope.  No sideloading.  Every app on a phone must be signed by Apple.  A free Apple account will let you install debug apps that will run for at most a week.  I *believe* a flutter release build will last until your membership (free or paid) expires, never more than a year.  But that's for your devices only.  You can't hand anything to a friend that they install.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios):

> In order to publish your app to the App Store, you must first enroll in the Apple Developer Program. You can read more about the various membership options in Apple’s Choosing a Membership guide.

Unfortunately, you will need to buy an Apple Developer Membership before being able to upload the app to AppStore. Same with Android but that side is "looser" in the sense that you can send someone the apk they can install. For iOS you'll need an app called TestFlight for other people to use the test version of your app, and cannot install the app otherwise unless it's on the AppStore.

You can read more on the free and paid tier of the program [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

[image]

Comment: oh I see, before I was in Android Studio, the project I created was then I built the apk and the results (app_debuk.apk) can be shared with other colleagues. mean for IOS can not be done like that?